# Get Microsecond Decimal Points of Current Time in C++

Tags: c++

I need to somehow get the decimal points of `time(0)` as microseconds. For example, if the time since epoch is `1486504815.415864` seconds, `time(0)` will only give me `1486504815` seconds. How can I get the `.415864` microseconds?

Comment: Use [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock).

Comment: i think you need [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now/)